# Calling soap requests in batch using Mulesoft

Tags: soap, salesforce, mule, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

I am trying to call a SOAP webservice deployed on Salesforce platform using mulesoft in batch format and I am unable to do that.

I have a scenario where I want to schedule the soap call invocation in batches.

My input is a scheduler and processor needs to aggregate my soap calls in a batch size of some number.

I am unable to do that because mule batch job expects array as an input and in my scenario I don't need any input other than scheduler to just invoke my apex webservice.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Mule Runtime are you using?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. It was 7.3.2 when I was using it.

Comment: Hi. That's the version of Anypoint Studio. The version of the Mule Runtime should be something like 4.1.x.